# Whant to check all kind of audio & video quality in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I check the quality and bit-rate of audio & video files in C# asp.net?

Answer (score 0):

if it is a *riff / wave* file the file can be examined on a binary level to get this kind of information, but it depends on exactly what kind of file.

https://ccrma.stanford.edu/courses/422/projects/WaveFormat/

Or you can use windows media player to get some information.

```
using WMPLib; 
// this file is called Interop.WMPLib.dll
WindowsMediaPlayerClass wmp = new WindowsMediaPlayerClass();
IWMPMedia mediaInfo = wmp.newMedia("myfile.wmv"); 

// write duration
Console.WriteLine("Duration = " + mediaInfo.duration);
// write named attributes
for (int i=0; i<mediaInfo.attributeCount; i++) {
Console.WriteLine(mediaInfo.getAttributeName(i) + " = " +  mediaInfo.getItemInfo(mediaInfo.getAttributeName(i)) );
}
```

[How to get the Interop.WMPLib.dll](http://www.devnewsgroups.net/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.windowsforms/topic62074.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.
Its work for only .wmv but i need to check all major video & audio (.mov, .swf, .rm, .mp3, .wmv, .flv etc) file quality including bit-rate, fram-rate etc