# Testing an Audio File Using C#

Tags: c#, .net, audio, audio-recording

I would like to write a script that tests a specific .WAV file and determines whether it was recorded fine or not. What I mean by this, is that I'm going to let several computers record the same input at the same time, save their audio files and at that point I need to see what computers did not manage to record it due to whatever reasons there might be.

I was thinking about checking the size of an audio file, but I'm not sure it is possible to say if a certain PC that had no actual recording in its output file did not pass the test, whilst another PC has passed it, basing only on the size of the output file.

I hope I'm clear enough about my question. Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) was my solution. I highly recommend using this library in similar cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the file attributes for sample rate , the higher the sample rate the better the quality. Like so , taken from here : [Whant to check all kind of audio & video quality in asp.net C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881245/whant-to-check-all-kind-of-audio-video-quality-in-asp-net-c-sharp)

```
    using WMPLib; 

    WindowsMediaPlayerClass wmp = new WindowsMediaPlayerClass();
    IWMPMedia mediaInfo = wmp.newMedia("myfile.wmv"); 

    // duration
    Console.WriteLine("Duration = " + mediaInfo.duration);

    // write named attributes
    for (int i=0; i<mediaInfo.attributeCount; i++) 
    {
      Console.WriteLine(mediaInfo.getAttributeName(i) + " = " +  m    ediaInfo.getItemInfo(mediaInfo.getAttributeName(i)) );
    }
```

Or use a 3rd part tool/library to test sound quality

Comment: Seems like the only attribute retrieved from a WAV file is its duration. On a different MP3 file, on the other hand, I have managed to retrieve a bigger amount of attributes, although none of them seemed to help me or be related to my case.